# Page partially loaded ( cdn.ampproject.org )

Tags: google-analytics, cdn

I am very new to this and i have the AMP plugin on my word press site.
The issue is that when i test my links in "Google Rich Results Testing tool "
I get this error "Page Loading issues"
How do i solve/ FIX this issue ?
Any help would be great.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It does not necessarily mean that your page will not load or that you are not eligible for your Rich Snippet to show. You might have an issue with your JavaScript or perhaps Robots.txt is blocking a file.